# why am I losing all gameObjects in unity when I have more then one scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a tower defense game and I made a menu scene and a level01 scene.
Now when I create some objects in the menu scene, and go to the level01 scene, I lose all my objects in my menu scene. I don't know what is going on. I have tried to create a new menu scene and duplicating my level01 scene, but it doesn't work.

Comment: When a scene is loaded in single mode, the default, all existing objects from the previous scene not marked as DontDestroyOnLoad are destroyed.

Comment: This is like saying "I drew a picture on one piece of paper, but when I get a new piece of paper my drawing isn't there." New scenes are *supposed* to wipe all the previous content unless you've specified another behavior as others below have outlined.

Comment: @Chuck The scene didn't have a camera or light so it is not normal

Comment: @Chunk also stuff keep disappearing

Answer (score 3):

You can use DontDestroyOnLoad or you can add multiple scenes and never unload the menu scene.

```
SceneManager.LoadScene("OtherSceneName", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of a scene, as its name implies, is to prescribe a different scene and arrangement. If you can design the gameplay inside a scene and deactivate them beforehand instead of adding objects. This will make the code more consistent and will prevent future problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark objects to keep them between loading scenes by `DontDestroyOnLoad(myObject)`. Here is the documentation with sample code:
[Object.DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)